# Integration question: how to solve the integration of the Quasi-binomial distribution

Tags: integration

The quasi-binomial score $U$ for one sample is defined as $$Q(\mu,y)= \int_{y}^{\mu} \frac{y-t}{t(1-t)} dt,\ y\in\{0,1\}.$$
How to solve this? The answer given in my note is $y\log\mu+\log(1-\mu).$ This could be incorrect. What is the correct answer?

What I have done is, $$Q(\mu,y)= \int_{y}^{\mu} \frac{y-t}{t(1-t)} dt = y\log(\frac{t}{1-t})|_y^{\mu}+\log(1-t)|_y^\mu.$$ Then I got stuck.

Comment: please add the `self-study` tag and look at the decomposition$$\frac{a-t}{t(1-t)}=\frac{b}{t}+\frac{c}{1-t}$$

Comment: Who is $x$ and who is $t$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $$\frac{y-t}{t(1-t)} = \frac{A}{t} + \frac{B}{1-t}$$ for constants $A, B$ with respect to $t$.  Then $$y-t = A(1-t) + Bt,$$ and setting $t = 0$ yields $y = A$, and setting $t = 1$ yields $B = y-1$.  Therefore $$\frac{y-t}{t(1-t)} = \frac{y}{t} + \frac{y-1}{1-t}$$ and $$\begin{align}
\int_{t=y}^\mu \frac{y-t}{t(1-t)} \, dt &= \left[y \log t + (1-y) \log (1-t) \right]_{t=y}^\mu \\
&= y \log \frac{\mu}{y} + (1-y) \log \frac{1-\mu}{1-y} \\
&= \log \frac{1-\mu}{1-y} + y \log \frac{\mu(1-y)}{y(1-\mu)} \tag{1}.
\end{align}$$
This does not match the claimed answer; e.g. choose $y = 1/4$, $\mu = 1/2$.  The results of numeric integration for these values is consistent with $(1)$.